# How to trigger javascript confirm alert to show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I created a confirm alert for throwing a message if a particular user's password is about to expired and request them to change their password.

I created a function for this in the header.
If user successfully logs in, they will be directed to the home page (where I call the function - `index.jsp`).
The confirm alert will show up (as expected) when user successfully login.
Then, each time user clicks the Home menu (`index.jsp` page), the confirm alert will show up again.

How to make it to show up only once?
I want to make it appear just when user successfully login to the page.

Anyone can help? Would appreciate it so much.

This is in the `header.jsp`:

```
function pwdAlert(){
  <%if(!headerexpDay.equals("") && Integer.parseInt(headerexpDay) <= 10 ){%>
    var expDay = "<%=headerexpDay%>";

    if(confirm("Your login password will be expired in "+expDay+" day(s). Do you want to change password?")){
      document.frmHeader.method = "POST";
      document.frmHeader.action= "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/admin/frmChangePassword.jsp";
      document.frmHeader.target= "_self";
      document.frmHeader.submit();
    }
  <%}%>
}
```

And this is in the `index.jsp` (home page) where I call the function.

```
<SCRIPT>
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      pwdAlert();
    }
  } 
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the message showing again if the user elects *not* to change the password? I assume if they change their password immediately then that stops it showing again, but you don't say so clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768067/display-alert-only-once

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry my bad, i didn't state it clearly. It supposed not to show up again when user selects No in the confirm alert.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of cookies, step can be described like bellow:

1. Read the cookie variable (name: isIgnored as an example)
2. If isIgnored === false, run your pwdAlert()
3. Inside your pwdAlert, change your code of promt

   ```
   if(confirm("Your login password will be expired in "+expDay+" day(s). Do you want to change password?")){ 
       // Your own code here
   } else {   
       // Set the cookie variable: isIgnored = true 
   }
   ```
4. This show how to use cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp