# How to show alert only once in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function which loads more post when user scroll below every time

here is the jquery code

```
$(function() {
    var $timeline = $('#tupdate'),
        $spinner = $('#loading').hide();

    function loadMore() {
        $(window).unbind('scroll.posts');
        $spinner.show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/loadmore?lastPost=" + $(".pointer:last").attr('id'),
            success: function(html) {
                if (html) {
                    $timeline.append(html);
                    $spinner.hide();
                } else {
                    $spinner.hide();
                    bootbox.alert('No more post available');
                }
                $(window).bind('scroll.posts', scrollEvent);
            }
        });
    }
    //lastAddedLiveFunc();
    $(window).bind('scroll.posts', scrollEvent);

    function scrollEvent() {
        var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            docheight = $(document).height(),
            winheight = $(window).height();
        var scrolltrigger = 0.95;
        if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) loadMore();
    }
});
```

Now the problem is whenever user scroll down popup is shown everytime which irritates the user, how can i alert only once?

here is what I've tried

```
if (!g) {
    var g = 1;
    bootbox.alert('No more Post');
}
```

but still it keeps on showing alert every time i scoll down

Comment: Create a cookie on that page and on other delete that cookie

Comment: you try is almost corre,t declare g out of the fonction with 0 value (var g = 0) and when you are in the if, change to g = 1

Comment: I don't think you should be using the alert box at all. You should try something else such as a final element that states there are no more items to load below the final element. You could also remove this item if they try to scroll and there suddenly _is_ something new to load.

Comment: You could also have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21567127/6049581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `g` inside the scope. I've renamed it to `showAlert` for readability.

```
  // Declare outside of `loadMore()`.
  var showAlert = true; // True by default.

  function loadMore(){

    $(window).unbind('scroll.posts');
    $spinner.show();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/ajax/loadmore?lastPost="+ $(".pointer:last").attr('id'),
      success: function(html){
          if(html){
              $timeline.append(html);
              $spinner.hide();
          }else{
            $spinner.hide();
              if (showAlert)
              {
                  bootbox.alert('No more post available');
                  showAlert = false; // don't show no more.
              }
          }

          $(window).bind('scroll.posts',scrollEvent);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a new variable with scope inside the callback which value can't get on next callback, so update the global variable. Also it's better to use Boolean value instead of number.

```
if(!g){
  g = true;
  bootbox.alert('No more Post'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `g` outside `$(function(){` to make it global.

So your code will look like this:

```
var g = false;

$(function() {
    var $timeline = $('#tupdate'),
        $spinner = $('#loading').hide();

    function loadMore() {
        $(window).unbind('scroll.posts');
        $spinner.show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/loadmore?lastPost=" + $(".pointer:last").attr('id'),
            success: function(html) {
                if (html) {
                    $timeline.append(html);
                    $spinner.hide();
                } else {
                    $spinner.hide();
                    if (!g) {
                        bootbox.alert('No more post available');
                    }
                }
                $(window).bind('scroll.posts', scrollEvent);
            }
        });
    }
    //lastAddedLiveFunc();
    $(window).bind('scroll.posts', scrollEvent);

    function scrollEvent() {
        var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            docheight = $(document).height(),
            winheight = $(window).height();
        var scrolltrigger = 0.95;
        if ((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) loadMore();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var` from

```
if(!g){
 g =1;
bootbox.alert('No more Post');
```

}

So g will be work as global variable.